# How to specify Icon as a string

Tags: c#, mudblazor

I am using MudBlazor which as a list of Icons implemented as svg strings.

This works fine, for example:

`<MudNavLink Href="fetchdata" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Home">Fetch data</MudNavLink>`

This generates this element:

```
<div class="mud-nav-item mud-ripple"><!--!--><a href="" rel="" class="mud-nav-link active"><!--!--><svg class="mud-icon-root mud-icon-default mud-svg-icon mud-icon-size-medium mud-nav-link-icon mud-nav-link-icon-default" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><!--!--><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z"></path></svg><div class="mud-nav-link-text">Home</div></a></div>
```

But now I want to data drive the list of Navigation items.  So I create a model, and then try to loop through the items and create the list dynamically.  This works except for the icon.  The icon is not set.

```
@foreach (var menuItem in this._navMenuList)
    {
        <MudNavLink Href="@menuItem.Href" Icon="@(menuItem.Icon)">@menuItem.Text</MudNavLink>
    }
```

This is what gets generated:

```
<div class="mud-nav-item mud-ripple"><!--!--><a href="" rel="" class="mud-nav-link active"><!--!--><span class="mud-icon-root mud-icon-default mud-icon-size-medium mud-nav-link-icon mud-nav-link-icon-default Icons.Material.Filled.Home"></span><div class="mud-nav-link-text">Home</div></a></div>
```

How do I make the Icon show up as expected?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got it to work:

```
<MudNavLink Href="@menuItem.Href" Icon="@(typeof(Icons.Material.Filled).GetField(menuItem.IconName)?.GetValue(null) as string)" >@menuItem.Text</MudNavLink>
```